# how to make JNI project work under all JB, KK and LP which compiled under one platform only

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk

I have a JNI project, this project can be compiled under Jelly Bean, KitKat, Lollipop.
My goal is compile one binary from JB or KK or LP and this binary should work under all JB, KK, LP. Since I do not want to compile it under all platform again if I only change a line to save maintenance cost.

Now I compile under KK, it works for LP. When compiling under LP, it works for KK also.

But when I compiled under JB, the binary did not work under KK (I did not test under LP yet, I guess it will not work).

The msg is like this:

> E/dalvikvm( 2680): dlopen("/system/lib/libmylib.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj" referenced by "libmylib.so"...
>
> W/dalvikvm( 2680): No implementation found for native Lcom/name1/name2/name3/Myclass;.native_setup:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)I

At this stage the function in the binary is not called yet.
I mean this one: `jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)`

I did a search and web said this issue is due to SQLCipher.

They are not related to each other.

My question is since JNI is C++ project, and we use ARM tools to compile, so the binary should compatible for JB, KK and LP.

I understood there are some API difference between JB, KK and LP.
However, if I only use API which are the same to JB, KK and LP, this binary should work for all.

At least for now, the so compiled under KK(LP) works under LP(KK)

Is there any secret under the hood?

Anyone can help on this?

Thanks.

## =========================================

Comment: You need to post your make file(s).  There is some settings there that may affect it.  It is not just the Android version, but also the processor that you are targeting that may cause the problem.  Are you testing just on the emulator, or on real devices?  If real, which ones?

Comment: If you get those errors, it seems like you are trying to link to android private headers and libraries. If you are doing that, you know that you don't get any guarantees on how things will work. If you build libraries that depend on platform internals, you need to build it separately for each platform.

Comment: make file at the bottom, cannot put it here.

Comment: When I tried to add make file as comment, it said too long, so I pasted one by one, but the format is not good. when I tried to edit my question, it made my question part as code and cannot save. And I should not put the make file as ans

Comment: I put the make file here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SesHstaERwabbAKZQm8sdi6deFRIVF4XeZR9BOnG_uo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Tested on real device. TI OMAP4, Qualcom Snapdragon MSM8960, Freescale IMX6.

Comment: If you build libraries that depend on platform internals, you need to build it separately for each platform. ===>This is correct. Seems the lib is the binder lib. But this also the goal I need independent JNI LIB.    Thanks for help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNI libraries for redistributable applications targeting multiple platforms should be built with the public NDK, not as part of a platform build. The makefile you linked indicates very much that it is built as part of the normal AOSP build system for building the full platform, and that it links to platform private libraries such as `libandroid_runtime`, `libnativehelper`, `libutils` and `libcutils`.

Comment: You are correct.
And this is the main principle to the do the JNI job with my purpose.
What I can achieve for now is very lucky (I mean KK-LP compatible).

I guess the original author is trying to use some advanced functions which is not available in the public NDK domain. (I verified the header files, a lot of function are not there compared to the local side.)

However, even in the public platform NDK side, I still prefer Android can provide the standard basics functions which are compatible for all the version.

Comment: I understand, they need to add new functionalities and break this rule.
Such as the kernel, they just added a field more in one structure, then changed the filed name.
Anyway, Android/Linux are great enough.

Thank you for spending time to look at this and gave a reply.
Really appreciated.

Comment: kernel = 3.4.0
/LINUX/android$ vi ./external/kernel-headers/original/linux/ion.h
246 struct ion_allocation_data {
247     size_t len;
248     size_t align;
249     unsigned int heap_mask;
250     unsigned int flags;
251     struct ion_handle *handle;
252 };


Kernel = 3.4.48 and 3.10.53
266 struct ion_allocation_data {
267     size_t len;
268     size_t align;
269     unsigned int heap_id_mask;
270     unsigned int flags;
271     struct ion_handle *handle;
272 };

Comment: Seems the web changed the format, and hard to read the code. Anyway, thanks you guys for help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Did a deep investigation: 
JNI lib linked with libbinder.so.

Under JB, it has such method:
nm ./out/target/product/xxxx/symbols/system/lib/libbinder.so |grep _ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj
00018c31 T _ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj
Under KK/LP, that lib does not have such method.

The binder lib I believe related to the SQLCipher.

So the reason is clear now: the linked lib is different and not compatible with each other. 
But for KK/LP, they are compatible.

Due to this reason, I do not think I can fulfill my goal.

However, KK/LP are working.
That's the good news.

Comment: Spent a lot of time on this issue. Now we know the root cause.